# `hbox` from `tcolobox` not working with left-aligned equations in amsmath

Tags: amsmath, tcolorbox, typography

I read through the manual and some questions here on TeX.SE that to restrict the size of a box produced using `tcolorbox` package I can use the `hbox` option.

If I use this option with `fleqn` passed to `amsmath` then the `hbox` fails. Please help me get these two to work together.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} %if this is commented things work fine

\usepackage{mathtools} %loads amsmath
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage[a4paper, scale=0.9]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!0!white,capture=hbox,arc=0mm]
\[
\begin{aligned}
    G(x_{1},x_{2}) &= \frac{\braket{ \overbrace{\ \ \Omega\ \ }^\text{vacuum} | \overbrace{T[ \hat{\phi}(\vec{x}_{1},t_{1})...\hat{\phi}(\vec{x}_{n},t_{n})]}^{\overbrace{\text{\footnotesize time-ordered product of operators}}^\text{\footnotesize earliest time to extreme right}} | \overbrace{\ \ \Omega\ \ }^\text{vacuum}}}{\braket{\Omega | \Omega}}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, never use `^\text{vacuum}` or similar. (1) It is dumb luck that `^\text` works in the first place, always use braces around arguments to `^` or `_`. (2) `\text` is the wrong command to use here. You want `vacuum` etc to be upright, but that is not what `\text` does. It follows the text outside math, so if that text is italics, the output of `\text` is italics. If the language is English, use `\mathrm{vacuum}` or even `\textnormal{vacuum}`. This misunderstanding abput `\text` is sadly very common

Comment: @daleif Yes yes, I realise the braces thing. This was just set-up in a hurry for MWE. I actually use snippets for `_` and `^` so that they automatically get replaced by `_{}` and `^{}`. I did not know the second point though. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tcolorbox` has support for the `amsmath` environments, you need the `theorems` library and the `empheq` package to access them. (I am using `align*` here because you use `aligned`, but it is not necessary to use it at this point, an `equation*` will do.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} %if this is commented things work fine

\usepackage{mathtools} %loads amsmath
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[a4paper, scale=0.9]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=gray!0!white,capture=hbox,arc=0mm}}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align*}
    G(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}) &= \frac{\braket{ \overbrace{\ \ \Omega\ \ }^\text{vacuum}
     | \overbrace{T[ \hat{\phi}(\vec{x}_{1},t_{1})\cdots\hat{\phi}(\vec{x}_{n},t_{n})]}^{\overbrace{\text{\footnotesize time-ordered product of operators}}^\text{\footnotesize earliest time to extreme right}} | \overbrace{\ \ \Omega\ \ }^\text{vacuum}}}{\braket{\Omega | \Omega}}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I personally would not use these `\overbrace`s, and changed the arguments of the Greens function.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, scale=0.9]{geometry}

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} %

\usepackage{mathtools} %loads amsmath
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=gray!0!white,capture=hbox,arc=0mm}}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align*}
    G(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}) &= \frac{\braket{\tikzmarknode{O1}{\Omega}
     | \overbrace{T[ \hat{\phi}(\vec{x}_{1},t_{1})\cdots\hat{\phi}(\vec{x}_{n},t_{n})]}^{
     \text{\footnotesize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      earliest time to extreme right\\
      time-ordered product of operators
\end{tabular}}} | 
     \tikzmarknode{O2}{\Omega}}}{\braket{\Omega | \Omega}}\quad
     \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \draw[latex-] (O1) -- ++ (120:0.9) node[above,font=\footnotesize]{vacuum};
     \draw[latex-] (O2) -- ++ (60:0.9) node[above,font=\footnotesize]{vacuum};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it better to use `substack` instead of `tabular` here?  Also, I haven't used `tikz` previously because it always seems like a lot of typing to achieve too little, specially while LaTeXing notes for video lectures.

Comment: @Nitin I used the tabular because then you are in text mode for both lines, and do not have to type two `\textrm` commands. The Ti*k*Z part is just a suggestion, whether or not it achieves little is something different users have different opinion on, I certainly use it for online lectures, especially with `beamer`. If you keep the `\overbraces` for the vacua, please follow daleifs suggestion. I also think that these things are sort of off-topic for the question, so these are just off-topic suggestions.